# Qt: mutually exclusive checkable menu items?

Tags: qt, menu

Many Windows programs have mutually exclusive checkable menu items. Qt Designer allows to make each individual item checkable or non-checkable. But is there a way to group a bunch of items and make them mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Qt just got what you need, you can use [QActionGroup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html) class.

Every action in the group will be automatically mutually exclusive.

```
#include <QActionGroup>

alignmentGroup = new QActionGroup(this);
alignmentGroup->addAction(leftAlignAct);
alignmentGroup->addAction(rightAlignAct);
alignmentGroup->addAction(justifyAct);
alignmentGroup->addAction(centerAct);
leftAlignAct->setChecked(true);
```

(picture from Qt official site)

[image]

Comment: You need to mark the actions as checkable in order to see this in the GUI. Use `leftAlignAct->setCheckable(true);` before `leftAlignAct->setChecked(true);`.

Comment: How are the `QActions` with the square box made?

Comment: @user3731622 Those are checkable actions added to a menu without being added to an action group. As such, they are independently checkable and become toggle/checkboxes.